# Progress bar should mirror the number of checkboxes checked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, progress-bar

Every time a check box is checked  I want to be able to add to the progress bar in increments.  So lets say if 1 out of 4 check boxes is check than it will equal to lets say 25 percent of the progress bar. Moreover if you uncheck one of the 4 check boxes the progress bar will decrease accordingly. This is what I have to which I am stuck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        int num1 = progressBar1.Maximum / 4;
        int num2 = progressBar1.Maximum / 4;
        int num3 = progressBar1.Maximum / 4;
        int num4 = progressBar1.Maximum / 4;
        int numAns;
        numAns = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;
        progressBar1.Value = numAns;
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {  


        }
        else if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
        {

        }
    }
    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    }
    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the same event handler for all of your checkboxes without making 4 methods for 4 checkboxes...

```
private const Int32 TOTAL_CHECKBOXES = 4;
private static Int32 s_Checks = 0;

private void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        ++s_Checks;
    else
        --s_Checks;

    progressBar.Value = s_Checks * (progressBar.Maximum / TOTAL_CHECKBOXES);
}
```

Comment: this really helped me a lot.  I should have put this in but forgot.  How do I make a button clear all of the checkboxes and resets the progressBar.

Comment: foreach (CheckBox cb in checkboxes) cb.Checked = false; progressBar.Value = progressBar.Minimum;

Answer (score 1):

Scrap the ProgressBar1_click, and for each box simply add (if Checked) or subtract (if not) 25 from ProgressBar1.Value on CheckedChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can wire up the same event to all checkboxes.  I added mine to a list, so that if you wanted to add more in the future, you could simply add the handler and add it to the list and you are done.

```
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckedChanged_1;
    checkBox2.CheckedChanged += CheckedChanged_1;
    checkBox3.CheckedChanged += CheckedChanged_1;
    checkBox4.CheckedChanged += CheckedChanged_1;

    checkboxesToCount.AddRange(new CheckBox[] {checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4});


}

private void CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 100 * checkboxesToCount.Count((c) => { return c.Checked; }) / checkboxesToCount.Count;
}
```